# Issues with seed setting in parallelised foreach loop R

Tags: r, foreach, data.table, doparallel

I have a selection of tests I want to run in parallel. When I do this using foreach(), I get the expected output of 20 test - iteration pairs:

```
## Without seed
require(data.table)
require(foreach)
require(iterators)
require(doParallel)
require(doRNG)

numCores = 2
registerDoParallel(numCores)

iterations = 5
num_tests = 2:5

foreach( i = 1:iterations, .combine = 'rbind', .multicombine = TRUE, .inorder = FALSE ) %:%
  foreach( n = num_tests, .combine = 'rbind', .multicombine = TRUE, .inorder = FALSE ) %dopar% {
    
    ## Print iteration
    print(paste('Tests =',n,'Iteration =',i))
    
  }
```

Output:

```
result.1 "Tests = 2 Iteration = 1"
result.2 "Tests = 3 Iteration = 1"
result.3 "Tests = 4 Iteration = 1"
result.4 "Tests = 5 Iteration = 1"
result.1 "Tests = 2 Iteration = 2"
result.2 "Tests = 3 Iteration = 2"
result.3 "Tests = 4 Iteration = 2"
result.4 "Tests = 5 Iteration = 2"
result.1 "Tests = 2 Iteration = 3"
result.2 "Tests = 3 Iteration = 3"
result.3 "Tests = 4 Iteration = 3"
result.4 "Tests = 5 Iteration = 3"
result.1 "Tests = 2 Iteration = 4"
result.2 "Tests = 3 Iteration = 4"
result.3 "Tests = 4 Iteration = 4"
result.4 "Tests = 5 Iteration = 4"
result.1 "Tests = 2 Iteration = 5"
result.2 "Tests = 3 Iteration = 5"
result.3 "Tests = 4 Iteration = 5"
result.4 "Tests = 5 Iteration = 5"
```

However, when I attempt to add a step to this loop that sets a random seed as described in the doRNG vignette, I get a different number of tests per iteration (14 test-iteration pairs):

```
## With seed
numCores = 2
registerDoParallel(numCores)

iterations = 5
num_tests = 2:5
rng <- RNGseq( iterations * (iterations+1) / 2, 1234)

foreach( i = 1:iterations, .combine = 'rbind', .multicombine = TRUE, .inorder = FALSE ) %:%
  foreach( n = num_tests, r = rng[(i-1)*i/2 + 1:i], .combine = 'rbind', .multicombine = TRUE, .inorder = FALSE ) %dopar% {
    
    ##Set seed
    rngtools::setRNG(r)
    
    ## Print iteration
    print(paste('Tests =',n,'Iteration =',i))
    
  }
```

Output:

```
result.1 "Tests = 2 Iteration = 1"
result.1 "Tests = 2 Iteration = 2"
result.2 "Tests = 3 Iteration = 2"
result.1 "Tests = 2 Iteration = 3"
result.2 "Tests = 3 Iteration = 3"
result.3 "Tests = 4 Iteration = 3"
result.1 "Tests = 2 Iteration = 4"
result.2 "Tests = 3 Iteration = 4"
result.3 "Tests = 4 Iteration = 4"
result.4 "Tests = 5 Iteration = 4"
result.1 "Tests = 2 Iteration = 5"
result.2 "Tests = 3 Iteration = 5"
result.3 "Tests = 4 Iteration = 5"
result.4 "Tests = 5 Iteration = 5"
```

I'm looking for a way to set seeds in parallel, nested foreach() loops with the correct number of iterations. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe see [this](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/doRNG/versions/1.8.2/topics/registerDoRNG)

Comment: As far as I can tell from the vignette, this is not compatible with nested loops. I get the following error when I try it: "Nested and/or conditional foreach loops using the operator %:% are not currently supported."

Comment: [Section 5](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/doRNG/vignettes/doRNG.pdf) describes workarounds.

Comment: Yes -- this is the workaround they suggested for my use case I think, but if I'm mistaken let me know.

Comment: Sorry :( Hopefully others may assist.

Answer (score 0):

This example in the vignette is overly clever, in my opinion. It establishes `r` as a sublist of `rng` within the `foreach` loop as a termination condition. You used some wrong indexes/list bounds, which is what's causing your confused output.

`r` is given an element of the `rng` sublist with each iteration. It gets away with it the bizarre sublist math, but it's incredibly confusing, and that line would earn a "WTF" in a code review 11 times out of 10.

As far as an immediate fix in closest alignment to the vignette's example:

```
## With seed
numCores = 2
registerDoParallel(numCores)

iterations = 5
num_tests = 2:5
rng <- RNGseq( iterations * length(num_tests), 1234)

foreach( i = 1:iterations, .combine = 'rbind', .multicombine = TRUE, .inorder = FALSE ) %:%
  foreach( n = num_tests, r = rng[(i-1)*length(num_tests) + 1:length(num_tests)], .combine = 'rbind', .multicombine = TRUE, .inorder = FALSE ) %dopar% {
    
    ##Set seed
    rngtools::setRNG(r)
    
    ## Print iteration
    print(paste('Tests =',n,'Iteration =',i))
    
  }
```

This changes

`rng <- RNGseq( iterations * (iterations+1) / 2, 1234)`

to

`rng <- RNGseq( iterations * length(num_tests), 1234)`

and changes

`r = rng[(i-1)*i/2 + 1:i]`

to

`r = rng[(i-1)*length(num_tests) + 1:length(num_tests)]`

## An alternate that might be more readable/understandable

`rng` is a list of `RNGSeq`s (they're just lists themselves), and all we want to do is select a new, single `RNGSeq` from that list for each of our parallel operations. We need an element for each of our independent, parallel iterations.

```
# one RNGseq for each inner+outer loop combination
iterations = 5
num_tests = 2:5
rng <- RNGseq(iterations * length(num_tests), 1234)

foreach( i = 1:iterations, .combine = 'rbind', .multicombine = TRUE, .inorder = FALSE ) %:%
    foreach( n = num_tests, .combine = 'rbind', .multicombine = TRUE, .inorder = FALSE ) %dopar% {
        
        # this is moved out of the loop termination conditions
        # and gets a new list element for each iteration
        # note the [[ ]]s to get a single element instead of a sublist!
        #         [-----------------------] conditions that change based on outer loop
        #                                     [---]  conditions that change based on inner loop
        r = rng[[ ((i-1)*length(num_tests)) + (n-1) ]]

        ##Set seed
        rngtools::setRNG(r)
        
        ## Print iteration
        print(paste('Tests =',n,'Iteration =',i))
        
    }
```

The assignment for `r` needs `(n-1)` because `num_tests` starts at 2. It would be more flexible to use the index of the current `n` in `num_tests`: `r = rng[ ((i-1)*i) + (which(num_tests == n)) ]`